# unable to iterate through csv DictReader more than once

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv

In Python(2.7.6) I am trying to get lists out of some columns of a CSV file.  Given the CSV file `test.csv` with the content:

```
COL_ONE,COL_TWO,COL_THREE
val_R1C1,val_R1C2,val_R1C3
val_R2C1,val_R2C2,val_R2C3
val_R3C1,val_R3C2,val_R3C3
val_R4C1,val_R4C2,val_R4C3
```

I expect the following code to do this for me:

```
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open("test.csv", "r"))
col2 = list(c2['COL_TWO'] for c2 in reader)
col3 = list(c3['COL_THREE'] for c3 in reader)
```

Unfortunately, when I print the two lists, col2 and col3, the second list is empty.

```
['val_R1C2', 'val_R2C2', 'val_R3C2', 'val_R4C2']
[]
```

This alternative has the same result:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("test.csv", "r"))
col2 = []
for c2 in reader:
    col2.append(c2['COL_TWO'])
col3 = []
for c3 in reader:
    col3.append(c3['COL_THREE'])
```

The workaround is easy:

```
col2 = []
col3 = []
for cval in reader:
    col2.append(cval['COL_TWO'])
    col3.append(cval['COL_THREE'])
```

I get what I would have expected in the previous two examples:

```
['val_R1C2', 'val_R2C2', 'val_R3C2', 'val_R4C2']
['val_R1C3', 'val_R2C3', 'val_R3C3', 'val_R4C3']
```

I would appreciate some help to understand what I am doing wrong. Why am I not getting the same results in all three cases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431752/python-csv-reader-how-do-i-return-to-the-top-of-the-file

Answer (score 0):

Rewind the underlying file to the 0 position in between reads:

```
import csv

fh = open("test.csv", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
next(reader) # skip header row
col2 = list(c2['COL_TWO'] for c2 in reader)
fh.seek(0)  ## <------------------- this is the point
next(reader) # skip header row
col3 = list(c3['COL_THREE'] for c3 in reader)
```

Comment: When I run this code and then print col2 and col3 I get:

    ['val_R1C2', 'val_R2C2', 'val_R3C2', 'val_R4C2']
    ['COL_THREE', 'val_R1C3', 'val_R2C3', 'val_R3C3', 'val_R4C3']

Comment: You are not showing at least a part of the code where you are skipping the first row of the file; I am going to edit my answer to provide for this, but please look into your code where this happens ...

Comment: logc, thanks for your explanation.  Actually, the code I have shown is complete save for two print statements at the end.  The code as you show it gives me `['val_R2C2', 'val_R3C2', 'val_R4C2']` `['val_R1C3', 'val_R2C3', 'val_R3C3', 'val_R4C3']` If I remove the first `next` statement, I get the desired result.